# How to make HTML SVG code within BootStrap "carousel-item" class responsive in mobile screen and small screen?

Tags: html, css, svg, bootstrap-4, responsive

I have a part of code, which is a big block of HTML svg, depicting the pictures that I want to draw in HTML.  This big block of code is within a  with BootStrap "carousel-item" class as below. However, when I tried to preview the effect, I found it wasn't able to be responsive when I resized the screen, or in a mobile screen.

For example, when I tried to view the picture that I drew in my mobile, I couldn't see it, because the pixel was not responsive with the carousel class. Even though carousel itself is responsive, the SVG part is not.

I haven't added anything in CSS yet.

The code is below.

```html
<div class="carousel-item active svg-container" style="height:352px;">
        <svg  height="100%" width="100%" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
            <line x1="0" y1="352px" x2="100%" y2="352px" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.4)" stroke-width="1"/>
            <g class="kitchen" transform="translate(400,0)">
                <g class="kitchen-cabinet" stroke-width="1.5">
                    <rect x="50" y="0" rx="3" ry="3" width="175" height="110" fill="none" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2)" filter="url(#f1)"/>
                    <line x1="137.5" y1="0" x2="137.5" y2="110" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.15)" />
                    <defs>
                        <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" width="110%" height="110%">
                        <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="2" dy="2" />
                        <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="1" />
                        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
                        </filter>
                    </defs>
                </g>
                <g class="kitchen-table" stroke-width="1">
                    <polygon points="-5.5,200 295.5,200 290,205 0,205" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.1)" fill="rgba(153, 102, 51, 0.5)"/>
                    <line x1="0" y1="265" x2="290" y2="265" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2)" />
                    <line x1="0" y1="205" x2="0" y2="100%" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.3)" />
                    <line x1="290" y1="205" x2="290" y2="100%" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.3)" />
                    <path id="kitchen-kettle" fill="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2)" d="M1136.74,509.923h-102.07c-3.036,0-6.035,0.782-8.664,2.257c-2.623,1.445-4.867,3.578-6.492,6.17L859.262,776.122
                    l-17.655-84.057c43.938-30.096,80.571-70.813,105.963-117.813c26.483-49.065,40.481-104.696,40.481-160.881
                    c0-65.256-18.516-128.539-53.546-183.009c-33.875-52.69-81.448-94.673-137.766-121.563c0.166-0.961,0.33-1.922,0.496-2.925
                    l0.466-2.79c1.075-6.449-0.691-13.101-4.972-18.726c-5.715-7.51-15.132-12.463-25.844-13.589
                    c-164.428-16.22-331.17-16.219-495.605,0.001c-10.705,1.125-20.123,6.077-25.838,13.588c-4.281,5.625-6.047,12.277-4.973,18.72
                    l0.433,2.644c0.17,1.031,0.329,2.022,0.486,3.012c-56.283,26.834-103.939,68.866-137.846,121.628
                    C68.515,284.833,50,348.116,50,413.371c0,56.184,13.998,111.815,40.481,160.882c25.508,47.21,62.334,88.063,106.586,118.256
                    l-74.045,352.551c-4.963,23.682,0.936,48.023,16.185,66.778c15.243,18.784,37.852,29.558,62.028,29.558h318.161h318.136
                    c24.167,0,46.784-10.772,62.055-29.558c15.231-18.766,21.121-43.107,16.16-66.778l-10.759-51.224
                    c63.816-0.731,108.188-47.532,135.596-143.067c13.684-47.695,21.321-99.839,28.06-145.845c4.112-28.069,7.995-54.58,12.613-74.716
                    c5.236-22.9,14.16-43.264,26.523-60.525c9.985-13.937,22.219-25.89,36.367-35.53c4.91-3.372,6.974-9.207,5.257-14.869
                    C1147.651,513.597,1142.68,509.923,1136.74,509.923z M188.251,1014.052c2.931-30.803,9.347-72.623,19.068-124.301
                    c16.52-87.817,37.172-174.998,37.38-175.867c0.788-3.323,4.12-5.38,7.447-4.589c3.324,0.789,5.379,4.124,4.589,7.447
                    c-0.201,0.846-20.287,85.638-36.64,172.028c-30.866,163.06-20.094,180.986-17.621,182.922
                    c24.801,11.26,234.416,13.742,313.081,13.742c3.417,0,6.186,2.769,6.186,6.186s-2.769,6.186-6.186,6.186
                    c-29.222,0-286.421-0.419-318.328-14.923C189.498,1079.371,183.061,1068.601,188.251,1014.052z M287.636,103.286
                    c2.78-0.396,280.087-39.395,465.474,0.072c3.342,0.712,5.474,3.997,4.763,7.339c-0.62,2.907-3.187,4.899-6.045,4.899
                    c-0.427,0-0.86-0.045-1.294-0.137c-183.222-39.007-458.383-0.324-461.141,0.072c-3.406,0.477-6.517-1.864-7.002-5.245
                    C281.907,106.905,284.254,103.77,287.636,103.286z M320.96,611.223c-2.992,0-5.487-2.124-6.062-4.946
                    c-0.081-0.401-0.124-0.815-0.124-1.24c0-0.423,0.043-0.836,0.124-1.235c0.572-2.825,3.068-4.951,6.062-4.951h364.451
                    c2.994,0,5.489,2.126,6.062,4.951c0.081,0.399,0.124,0.812,0.124,1.235c0,0.425-0.043,0.839-0.125,1.24
                    c-0.575,2.823-3.069,4.946-6.061,4.946H320.96z M633.6,1091.621c0,3.417-2.769,6.186-6.186,6.186h-49.281
                    c-3.417,0-6.186-2.769-6.186-6.186s2.769-6.186,6.186-6.186h49.281C630.83,1085.435,633.6,1088.204,633.6,1091.621z
                    M207.183,644.343c-33.961-26.496-62.124-60.789-81.499-99.319c-20.601-41.022-31.046-85.317-31.046-131.653
                    c0-54.592,15.022-107.793,43.441-153.854c27.179-44.094,65.552-80.124,111.045-104.339c0.001,0.008,0.003,0.016,0.004,0.024
                    l0.203,1.23c2.561,15.401,19.575,26.361,37.913,24.436c153.839-15.123,309.847-15.122,463.68-0.001
                    c1.411,0.149,2.813,0.221,4.201,0.221c16.683,0,31.353-10.435,33.695-24.646c0.071-0.406,0.131-0.803,0.196-1.206
                    c45.458,24.206,83.808,60.22,110.959,104.281c28.418,46.102,43.44,99.303,43.44,153.854c0,46.304-10.453,90.598-31.07,131.653
                    c-19.208,38.248-47.111,72.333-80.861,98.832l-4.962-23.628c-0.964-4.624-3.526-8.813-7.207-11.791
                    c-3.661-2.989-8.288-4.635-13.032-4.635h-53.733l-18.997-34.229c-1.775-3.191-4.396-5.876-7.58-7.765
                    c-3.19-1.875-6.82-2.867-10.499-2.867h-79.171l-14.413-24.214c-1.843-3.092-4.456-5.65-7.545-7.392
                    c-3.076-1.776-6.61-2.715-10.219-2.715h-52.967c-0.332-3.841-1.181-17.497,2.01-31.041c4.94-20.976,16.781-31.61,35.194-31.61
                    c9.092,0,17.169-1.908,24.005-5.671c5.699-3.138,10.571-7.621,14.48-13.328c4.341-6.365,4.707-14.256,0.979-21.111
                    c-3.731-6.832-10.574-10.913-18.308-10.913h-90.118h-90.144c-7.734,0-14.577,4.08-18.309,10.915
                    c-3.715,6.834-3.35,14.723,0.982,21.111c3.909,5.704,8.78,10.188,14.479,13.325c6.835,3.764,14.911,5.671,24.005,5.671
                    c18.445,0,30.285,10.635,35.194,31.61c3.187,13.53,2.339,27.198,2.009,31.041h-52.965c-3.609,0-7.143,0.939-10.208,2.709
                    c-3.1,1.748-5.714,4.306-7.556,7.397l-14.414,24.215h-77.612c-3.689,0-7.312,0.992-10.475,2.867
                    c-3.195,1.88-5.824,4.565-7.604,7.766l-18.997,34.227h-55.292c-4.743,0-9.371,1.646-13.027,4.631
                    c-3.685,2.981-6.248,7.17-7.213,11.793L207.183,644.343z" transform="scale(0.053) translate(350,2620)"/>
                    <g class="coffee-cup">
                        <g transform="translate(120,20)" style="fill:none;stroke:rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.3); stroke-width:2/5px;stroke-linecap:round;">
                            <path id="s1" d="M115,130 q6,6,1,9 t0,8" />
                            <path id="s2" d="M115,130 q6,6,1,9 t0,8" transform="translate(8,0)" />
                            <path id="s3" d="M115,130 q6,6,1,9 t0,8" transform="translate(16,0)" />
                        </g> 
                        <g transform="translate(223,165)" style="fill:rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2);">
                        <path d="m 4.435,6.66 c 0.24,5.48 3.3455,19.43 6.9145,22.915 l 9.12,0 9.125,0 c 1.46,-1.455 2.075,-5.83 3.575,-9.6 0.61,-1.525 2.405,-8.38 2.73,-8.265 7.325,-1.41 4.72,10.095 -3.19,9.52
                                    -0.975,1.895 -1.705,3.845 -1.76,3.805 14.515,-4.01 14.125,-14.385 5.7985,-15.67 -0.44,-0.674 0.405,-2.08 0.175,-2.795 l -16.455,-0.45 z M -0.9995,29.895 c 1.1085,2.5585 5.11,4.03 7.325,4.49 l 14.705,0 14.7015,0 c 2.215,-0.4595 6.105,-1.81 7.2145,-4.37 l -20.62,0.235 z" />
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g class="flowerpot" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.4)" stroke-width="1" >
                <path fill="none" opacity="1"
                    d="M103,171 C 102,207 105,226 118,238 L183,238 C 195,228 200,205 198,170.5" transform="translate(750,113)"/>
                <line x1="852.5" y1="283.5" x2="948.3" y2="283.5" />
            </g>
            <g class="plant" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.4)" stroke-width="1" >
                <line x1="900" y1="150" x2="900" y2="283.5" />
                <path fill="none" opacity="1" transform="translate(750,20)"
                      d="M149,244 C 135,240 120,246 100,217 C 126,218 137,228 150,244 C 164,224 172,219 191,218 C 183,239 169,241 150,244" />
                <path fill="none" opacity="1" transform="translate(750,15)"
                d="M150,209 C 127,209 108,202 90,176 C 126,179 135,191 150,208 C 157,189 176,177 197,176 C 181,208 165,208 149,209" />

                <path fill="none" opacity="1" transform="translate(728,-10) scale(1.15)"
                      d="M150,168 C 133,166 122,159 114,148 C 130,149 141,153 150,167 C 155,151 166,148 178,145 C 170,163 159,167 150,168" />
            </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
```

And

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your application responsive, you need to make a few code changes:

1. Instead of `y2 = "100%"` set `y2 = "352"`

```
<line x1="0" y1="205" x2="0" y2="352" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.3)" />
 <line x1="290" y1="205" x2="290" y2="352" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.3)" />
```

2. Remove from SVG styles `style = "height: 352px;"` - fixed size prevents the application from being responsive
3. Remove `preserveAspectRatio ="none"` as this violates the proportional change of the sides
   The default in SVG is `preserveAspectRatio =" xMidYMid meet "`
4. Add `viewBox = "0 0 1365 352"`
5. Add `width` and `height` in relative units to parent container `.svg-container`

```css
.svg-container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-item active svg-container" >
        <svg id="svg1"   viewBox="0 0 1365 352 " version="1.1" >
            <line x1="0" y1="352px" x2="100%" y2="352px" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.4)" stroke-width="1"/>
            <g class="kitchen" transform="translate(400,0)">
                <g class="kitchen-cabinet" stroke-width="1.5">
                    <rect x="50" y="0" rx="3" ry="3" width="175" height="110" fill="none" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2)" filter="url(#f1)"/>
                    <line x1="137.5" y1="0" x2="137.5" y2="110" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.15)" />
                    <defs>
                        <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" width="110%" height="110%">
                        <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="2" dy="2" />
                        <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="1" />
                        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
                        </filter>
                    </defs>
                </g>
                <g class="kitchen-table" stroke-width="1">
                    <polygon points="-5.5,200 295.5,200 290,205 0,205" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.1)" fill="rgba(153, 102, 51, 0.5)"/>
                    <line x1="0" y1="265" x2="290" y2="265" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2)" />
                    <line x1="0" y1="205" x2="0" y2="352" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.3)" />
                    <line x1="290" y1="205" x2="290" y2="352" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.3)" />
                    <path id="kitchen-kettle" fill="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2)" d="M1136.74,509.923h-102.07c-3.036,0-6.035,0.782-8.664,2.257c-2.623,1.445-4.867,3.578-6.492,6.17L859.262,776.122
                    l-17.655-84.057c43.938-30.096,80.571-70.813,105.963-117.813c26.483-49.065,40.481-104.696,40.481-160.881
                    c0-65.256-18.516-128.539-53.546-183.009c-33.875-52.69-81.448-94.673-137.766-121.563c0.166-0.961,0.33-1.922,0.496-2.925
                    l0.466-2.79c1.075-6.449-0.691-13.101-4.972-18.726c-5.715-7.51-15.132-12.463-25.844-13.589
                    c-164.428-16.22-331.17-16.219-495.605,0.001c-10.705,1.125-20.123,6.077-25.838,13.588c-4.281,5.625-6.047,12.277-4.973,18.72
                    l0.433,2.644c0.17,1.031,0.329,2.022,0.486,3.012c-56.283,26.834-103.939,68.866-137.846,121.628
                    C68.515,284.833,50,348.116,50,413.371c0,56.184,13.998,111.815,40.481,160.882c25.508,47.21,62.334,88.063,106.586,118.256
                    l-74.045,352.551c-4.963,23.682,0.936,48.023,16.185,66.778c15.243,18.784,37.852,29.558,62.028,29.558h318.161h318.136
                    c24.167,0,46.784-10.772,62.055-29.558c15.231-18.766,21.121-43.107,16.16-66.778l-10.759-51.224
                    c63.816-0.731,108.188-47.532,135.596-143.067c13.684-47.695,21.321-99.839,28.06-145.845c4.112-28.069,7.995-54.58,12.613-74.716
                    c5.236-22.9,14.16-43.264,26.523-60.525c9.985-13.937,22.219-25.89,36.367-35.53c4.91-3.372,6.974-9.207,5.257-14.869
                    C1147.651,513.597,1142.68,509.923,1136.74,509.923z M188.251,1014.052c2.931-30.803,9.347-72.623,19.068-124.301
                    c16.52-87.817,37.172-174.998,37.38-175.867c0.788-3.323,4.12-5.38,7.447-4.589c3.324,0.789,5.379,4.124,4.589,7.447
                    c-0.201,0.846-20.287,85.638-36.64,172.028c-30.866,163.06-20.094,180.986-17.621,182.922
                    c24.801,11.26,234.416,13.742,313.081,13.742c3.417,0,6.186,2.769,6.186,6.186s-2.769,6.186-6.186,6.186
                    c-29.222,0-286.421-0.419-318.328-14.923C189.498,1079.371,183.061,1068.601,188.251,1014.052z M287.636,103.286
                    c2.78-0.396,280.087-39.395,465.474,0.072c3.342,0.712,5.474,3.997,4.763,7.339c-0.62,2.907-3.187,4.899-6.045,4.899
                    c-0.427,0-0.86-0.045-1.294-0.137c-183.222-39.007-458.383-0.324-461.141,0.072c-3.406,0.477-6.517-1.864-7.002-5.245
                    C281.907,106.905,284.254,103.77,287.636,103.286z M320.96,611.223c-2.992,0-5.487-2.124-6.062-4.946
                    c-0.081-0.401-0.124-0.815-0.124-1.24c0-0.423,0.043-0.836,0.124-1.235c0.572-2.825,3.068-4.951,6.062-4.951h364.451
                    c2.994,0,5.489,2.126,6.062,4.951c0.081,0.399,0.124,0.812,0.124,1.235c0,0.425-0.043,0.839-0.125,1.24
                    c-0.575,2.823-3.069,4.946-6.061,4.946H320.96z M633.6,1091.621c0,3.417-2.769,6.186-6.186,6.186h-49.281
                    c-3.417,0-6.186-2.769-6.186-6.186s2.769-6.186,6.186-6.186h49.281C630.83,1085.435,633.6,1088.204,633.6,1091.621z
                    M207.183,644.343c-33.961-26.496-62.124-60.789-81.499-99.319c-20.601-41.022-31.046-85.317-31.046-131.653
                    c0-54.592,15.022-107.793,43.441-153.854c27.179-44.094,65.552-80.124,111.045-104.339c0.001,0.008,0.003,0.016,0.004,0.024
                    l0.203,1.23c2.561,15.401,19.575,26.361,37.913,24.436c153.839-15.123,309.847-15.122,463.68-0.001
                    c1.411,0.149,2.813,0.221,4.201,0.221c16.683,0,31.353-10.435,33.695-24.646c0.071-0.406,0.131-0.803,0.196-1.206
                    c45.458,24.206,83.808,60.22,110.959,104.281c28.418,46.102,43.44,99.303,43.44,153.854c0,46.304-10.453,90.598-31.07,131.653
                    c-19.208,38.248-47.111,72.333-80.861,98.832l-4.962-23.628c-0.964-4.624-3.526-8.813-7.207-11.791
                    c-3.661-2.989-8.288-4.635-13.032-4.635h-53.733l-18.997-34.229c-1.775-3.191-4.396-5.876-7.58-7.765
                    c-3.19-1.875-6.82-2.867-10.499-2.867h-79.171l-14.413-24.214c-1.843-3.092-4.456-5.65-7.545-7.392
                    c-3.076-1.776-6.61-2.715-10.219-2.715h-52.967c-0.332-3.841-1.181-17.497,2.01-31.041c4.94-20.976,16.781-31.61,35.194-31.61
                    c9.092,0,17.169-1.908,24.005-5.671c5.699-3.138,10.571-7.621,14.48-13.328c4.341-6.365,4.707-14.256,0.979-21.111
                    c-3.731-6.832-10.574-10.913-18.308-10.913h-90.118h-90.144c-7.734,0-14.577,4.08-18.309,10.915
                    c-3.715,6.834-3.35,14.723,0.982,21.111c3.909,5.704,8.78,10.188,14.479,13.325c6.835,3.764,14.911,5.671,24.005,5.671
                    c18.445,0,30.285,10.635,35.194,31.61c3.187,13.53,2.339,27.198,2.009,31.041h-52.965c-3.609,0-7.143,0.939-10.208,2.709
                    c-3.1,1.748-5.714,4.306-7.556,7.397l-14.414,24.215h-77.612c-3.689,0-7.312,0.992-10.475,2.867
                    c-3.195,1.88-5.824,4.565-7.604,7.766l-18.997,34.227h-55.292c-4.743,0-9.371,1.646-13.027,4.631
                    c-3.685,2.981-6.248,7.17-7.213,11.793L207.183,644.343z" transform="scale(0.053) translate(350,2620)"/>
                    <g class="coffee-cup">
                        <g transform="translate(120,20)" style="fill:none;stroke:rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.3); stroke-width:2/5px;stroke-linecap:round;">
                            <path id="s1" d="M115,130 q6,6,1,9 t0,8" />
                            <path id="s2" d="M115,130 q6,6,1,9 t0,8" transform="translate(8,0)" />
                            <path id="s3" d="M115,130 q6,6,1,9 t0,8" transform="translate(16,0)" />
                        </g> 
                        <g transform="translate(223,165)" style="fill:rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2);">
                        <path d="m 4.435,6.66 c 0.24,5.48 3.3455,19.43 6.9145,22.915 l 9.12,0 9.125,0 c 1.46,-1.455 2.075,-5.83 3.575,-9.6 0.61,-1.525 2.405,-8.38 2.73,-8.265 7.325,-1.41 4.72,10.095 -3.19,9.52
                                    -0.975,1.895 -1.705,3.845 -1.76,3.805 14.515,-4.01 14.125,-14.385 5.7985,-15.67 -0.44,-0.674 0.405,-2.08 0.175,-2.795 l -16.455,-0.45 z M -0.9995,29.895 c 1.1085,2.5585 5.11,4.03 7.325,4.49 l 14.705,0 14.7015,0 c 2.215,-0.4595 6.105,-1.81 7.2145,-4.37 l -20.62,0.235 z" />
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g class="flowerpot" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.4)" stroke-width="1" >
                <path fill="none" opacity="1"
                    d="M103,171 C 102,207 105,226 118,238 L183,238 C 195,228 200,205 198,170.5" transform="translate(750,113)"/>
                <line x1="852.5" y1="283.5" x2="948.3" y2="283.5" />
            </g>
            <g class="plant" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.4)" stroke-width="1" >
                <line x1="900" y1="150" x2="900" y2="283.5" />
                <path fill="none" opacity="1" transform="translate(750,20)"
                      d="M149,244 C 135,240 120,246 100,217 C 126,218 137,228 150,244 C 164,224 172,219 191,218 C 183,239 169,241 150,244" />
                <path fill="none" opacity="1" transform="translate(750,15)"
                d="M150,209 C 127,209 108,202 90,176 C 126,179 135,191 150,208 C 157,189 176,177 197,176 C 181,208 165,208 149,209" />

                <path fill="none" opacity="1" transform="translate(728,-10) scale(1.15)"
                      d="M150,168 C 133,166 122,159 114,148 C 130,149 141,153 150,167 C 155,151 166,148 178,145 C 170,163 159,167 150,168" />
            </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
      
      <script>
      let bb = svg1.getBBox();
         console.log(bb);
      </script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You help me solve my problem :) It does work!

Comment: I am interested in learning how to do that. Actually I also have another question about the responsive svg, are you an expert of svg? :D

Comment: @RouyuChen As it suits you, you can ask a separate question on adaptability SVG. On animation I will answer right in this topic

Comment: That's cool, I am quite new to stackoverflow so I am still learning how to use that efficiently. Anyway, nice to see you here! I will ask a separate question about responsive SVG soon. p.s. I don't know how to follow someone in stackoverflow, I wanted to flow you, haha :)

Comment: @Gloria Chen  Finding a stackoverflow user is not difficult Select "Users" in the left sidebar and enter the member's nickname  Have you changed your name and avatar?

Comment: I want to follow you, can I? Yeah I just changed my nickname and avatar :)

Answer (score 2):

### Object animation

There are two kinds of animations used:

1. **stroke-dashoffset** Changes from the maximum line length to zero
   For drawing outlines of lines of kitchen items
2. **animate fill** - for painting objects

I will show you how both animations work on one subject.

```html
<div class="carousel-item active svg-container" >
        <svg id="svg1"   viewBox="0 0 1365 352 " version="1.1" >
            <line x1="0" y1="352px" x2="100%" y2="352px" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.4)" stroke-width="1"/>
         <g class="coffee-cup" transform="scale(3) translate(-120,-120)">
                        <g transform="translate(120,20)" style="fill:none;stroke:rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.3); stroke-width:2/5px;stroke-linecap:round; stroke-dasharray:21; stroke-dashoffset:21;">
                            <path id="s1" d="M115,130 q6,6,1,9 t0,8" />
                            <path id="s2" d="M115,130 q6,6,1,9 t0,8" transform="translate(8,0)" />
                            <path id="s3" d="M115,130 q6,6,1,9 t0,8" transform="translate(16,0)" />
                             <!-- Smoke animation above the cup -->
                            <animate id="an_smoke" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_fill_cup.end-0.5s" dur="1s" values="21;0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
                        </g> 
                        <g transform="translate(223,165)" style="stroke:rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2);fill:none;stroke-dasharray:234;stroke-dashoffset:234">
                        <path d="m 4.435,6.66 c 0.24,5.48 3.3455,19.43 6.9145,22.915 l 9.12,0 9.125,0 c 1.46,-1.455 2.075,-5.83 3.575,-9.6 0.61,-1.525 2.405,-8.38 2.73,-8.265 7.325,-1.41 4.72,10.095 -3.19,9.52
                                    -0.975,1.895 -1.705,3.845 -1.76,3.805 14.515,-4.01 14.125,-14.385 5.7985,-15.67 -0.44,-0.674 0.405,-2.08 0.175,-2.795 l -16.455,-0.45 z M -0.9995,29.895 c 1.1085,2.5585 5.11,4.03 7.325,4.49 l 14.705,0 14.7015,0 c 2.215,-0.4595 6.105,-1.81 7.2145,-4.37 l -20.62,0.235 z" >
                       
                           <!-- Animation of drawing the contours of a cup                       -->
                        <animate id="an_cup_body" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="3s" values="234;0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />  
                               <!-- Cup fill animation                       -->
                        <animate id="an_fill_cup" attributeName="fill" begin="an_cup_body.end-1s" dur="1s" from="transparent" to="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2)" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
                        </path>         
                        </g>
                    </g>    
            <text x="100" y="100" font-size="36px" fill="black">Click me </text> 
 </svg>
      </div>
```

```
   <!-- Animation of drawing the contours of a cup                       -->
        <animate id="an_cup_body" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" 
          begin="svg1.click" dur="4s" values="234;0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
```

With this animation, the `stroke-dashoffset` decreases from a maximum value equal to the length of the `234px` line to zero. Therefore, the line will be drawn from zero to maximum

```
   <!-- Cup fill animation                       -->
<animate id="an_fill_cup" attributeName="fill" 
     begin="an_cup_body.end-1s" dur="1s" from="transparent" to="rgba(76, 61, 104,.2)"
       fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
```

Color change animation from transparent to gray

The animation of other items in the application is implemented in the same way.

Below is the complete code:

```css
.svg-container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<style>
.svg-container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
</style>
<div class="carousel-item active svg-container" >
        <svg id="svg1"   viewBox="0 0 1365 352 " version="1.1" >
            <line x1="0" y1="352px" x2="100%" y2="352px" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.4)" stroke-width="1"/>
            <g class="kitchen" transform="translate(400,0)">
                <g class="kitchen-cabinet" stroke-width="1.5">
                    <rect x="50" y="0" rx="3" ry="3" width="175" height="110" fill="none" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2)" filter="url(#f1)"/>
                    <line x1="137.5" y1="0" x2="137.5" y2="110" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.15)" />
                    <defs>
                        <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" width="110%" height="110%">
                        <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="2" dy="2" />
                        <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="1" />
                        <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
                        </filter>
                    </defs>
                </g>
                <g class="kitchen-table" stroke-width="1">
                    <polygon points="-5.5,200 295.5,200 290,205 0,205" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.1)" fill="rgba(153, 102, 51, 0.5)"/>
                    <line x1="0" y1="265" x2="290" y2="265" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2)" />
                    <line x1="0" y1="205" x2="0" y2="352" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.3)" />
                    <line x1="290" y1="205" x2="290" y2="352" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.3)" />
                    
                    <path id="kitchen-kettle" fill="none" stroke-width="25" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2)" stroke-dashoffset="5000" stroke-dasharray="5000" d="M1136.74,509.923h-102.07c-3.036,0-6.035,0.782-8.664,2.257c-2.623,1.445-4.867,3.578-6.492,6.17L859.262,776.122
                    l-17.655-84.057c43.938-30.096,80.571-70.813,105.963-117.813c26.483-49.065,40.481-104.696,40.481-160.881
                    c0-65.256-18.516-128.539-53.546-183.009c-33.875-52.69-81.448-94.673-137.766-121.563c0.166-0.961,0.33-1.922,0.496-2.925
                    l0.466-2.79c1.075-6.449-0.691-13.101-4.972-18.726c-5.715-7.51-15.132-12.463-25.844-13.589
                    c-164.428-16.22-331.17-16.219-495.605,0.001c-10.705,1.125-20.123,6.077-25.838,13.588c-4.281,5.625-6.047,12.277-4.973,18.72
                    l0.433,2.644c0.17,1.031,0.329,2.022,0.486,3.012c-56.283,26.834-103.939,68.866-137.846,121.628
                    C68.515,284.833,50,348.116,50,413.371c0,56.184,13.998,111.815,40.481,160.882c25.508,47.21,62.334,88.063,106.586,118.256
                    l-74.045,352.551c-4.963,23.682,0.936,48.023,16.185,66.778c15.243,18.784,37.852,29.558,62.028,29.558h318.161h318.136
                    c24.167,0,46.784-10.772,62.055-29.558c15.231-18.766,21.121-43.107,16.16-66.778l-10.759-51.224
                    c63.816-0.731,108.188-47.532,135.596-143.067c13.684-47.695,21.321-99.839,28.06-145.845c4.112-28.069,7.995-54.58,12.613-74.716
                    c5.236-22.9,14.16-43.264,26.523-60.525c9.985-13.937,22.219-25.89,36.367-35.53c4.91-3.372,6.974-9.207,5.257-14.869
                    C1147.651,513.597,1142.68,509.923,1136.74,509.923z M188.251,1014.052c2.931-30.803,9.347-72.623,19.068-124.301
                    c16.52-87.817,37.172-174.998,37.38-175.867c0.788-3.323,4.12-5.38,7.447-4.589c3.324,0.789,5.379,4.124,4.589,7.447
                    c-0.201,0.846-20.287,85.638-36.64,172.028c-30.866,163.06-20.094,180.986-17.621,182.922
                    c24.801,11.26,234.416,13.742,313.081,13.742c3.417,0,6.186,2.769,6.186,6.186s-2.769,6.186-6.186,6.186
                    c-29.222,0-286.421-0.419-318.328-14.923C189.498,1079.371,183.061,1068.601,188.251,1014.052z M287.636,103.286
                    c2.78-0.396,280.087-39.395,465.474,0.072c3.342,0.712,5.474,3.997,4.763,7.339c-0.62,2.907-3.187,4.899-6.045,4.899
                    c-0.427,0-0.86-0.045-1.294-0.137c-183.222-39.007-458.383-0.324-461.141,0.072c-3.406,0.477-6.517-1.864-7.002-5.245
                    C281.907,106.905,284.254,103.77,287.636,103.286z M320.96,611.223c-2.992,0-5.487-2.124-6.062-4.946
                    c-0.081-0.401-0.124-0.815-0.124-1.24c0-0.423,0.043-0.836,0.124-1.235c0.572-2.825,3.068-4.951,6.062-4.951h364.451
                    c2.994,0,5.489,2.126,6.062,4.951c0.081,0.399,0.124,0.812,0.124,1.235c0,0.425-0.043,0.839-0.125,1.24
                    c-0.575,2.823-3.069,4.946-6.061,4.946H320.96z M633.6,1091.621c0,3.417-2.769,6.186-6.186,6.186h-49.281
                    c-3.417,0-6.186-2.769-6.186-6.186s2.769-6.186,6.186-6.186h49.281C630.83,1085.435,633.6,1088.204,633.6,1091.621z
                    M207.183,644.343c-33.961-26.496-62.124-60.789-81.499-99.319c-20.601-41.022-31.046-85.317-31.046-131.653
                    c0-54.592,15.022-107.793,43.441-153.854c27.179-44.094,65.552-80.124,111.045-104.339c0.001,0.008,0.003,0.016,0.004,0.024
                    l0.203,1.23c2.561,15.401,19.575,26.361,37.913,24.436c153.839-15.123,309.847-15.122,463.68-0.001
                    c1.411,0.149,2.813,0.221,4.201,0.221c16.683,0,31.353-10.435,33.695-24.646c0.071-0.406,0.131-0.803,0.196-1.206
                    c45.458,24.206,83.808,60.22,110.959,104.281c28.418,46.102,43.44,99.303,43.44,153.854c0,46.304-10.453,90.598-31.07,131.653
                    c-19.208,38.248-47.111,72.333-80.861,98.832l-4.962-23.628c-0.964-4.624-3.526-8.813-7.207-11.791
                    c-3.661-2.989-8.288-4.635-13.032-4.635h-53.733l-18.997-34.229c-1.775-3.191-4.396-5.876-7.58-7.765
                    c-3.19-1.875-6.82-2.867-10.499-2.867h-79.171l-14.413-24.214c-1.843-3.092-4.456-5.65-7.545-7.392
                    c-3.076-1.776-6.61-2.715-10.219-2.715h-52.967c-0.332-3.841-1.181-17.497,2.01-31.041c4.94-20.976,16.781-31.61,35.194-31.61
                    c9.092,0,17.169-1.908,24.005-5.671c5.699-3.138,10.571-7.621,14.48-13.328c4.341-6.365,4.707-14.256,0.979-21.111
                    c-3.731-6.832-10.574-10.913-18.308-10.913h-90.118h-90.144c-7.734,0-14.577,4.08-18.309,10.915
                    c-3.715,6.834-3.35,14.723,0.982,21.111c3.909,5.704,8.78,10.188,14.479,13.325c6.835,3.764,14.911,5.671,24.005,5.671
                    c18.445,0,30.285,10.635,35.194,31.61c3.187,13.53,2.339,27.198,2.009,31.041h-52.965c-3.609,0-7.143,0.939-10.208,2.709
                    c-3.1,1.748-5.714,4.306-7.556,7.397l-14.414,24.215h-77.612c-3.689,0-7.312,0.992-10.475,2.867
                    c-3.195,1.88-5.824,4.565-7.604,7.766l-18.997,34.227h-55.292c-4.743,0-9.371,1.646-13.027,4.631
                    c-3.685,2.981-6.248,7.17-7.213,11.793L207.183,644.343z" transform="scale(0.053) translate(350,2620)">
                        <!-- Teapot outline drawing animation -->
                    <animate id="an_kettle" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="4s" values="5000;0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />  
                            <!-- Teapot Grayscale Animation                   -->
                     <animate attributeName="fill" begin="an_kettle.end-1s" dur="1s" from="transparent" to="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2)" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
                    
                    </path
                    <g class="coffee-cup">
                        <g transform="translate(120,20)" style="fill:none;stroke:rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.3); stroke-width:2/5px;stroke-linecap:round; stroke-dasharray:21; stroke-dashoffset:21;">
                            <path id="s1" d="M115,130 q6,6,1,9 t0,8" />
                            <path id="s2" d="M115,130 q6,6,1,9 t0,8" transform="translate(8,0)" />
                            <path id="s3" d="M115,130 q6,6,1,9 t0,8" transform="translate(16,0)" />
                             <!-- Smoke animation above the cup -->
                            <animate id="an_smoke" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_fill_cup.end" dur="1s" values="21;0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
                        </g> 
                        <g transform="translate(223,165)" style="stroke:rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2);fill:none;stroke-dasharray:234;stroke-dashoffset:234">
                        <path d="m 4.435,6.66 c 0.24,5.48 3.3455,19.43 6.9145,22.915 l 9.12,0 9.125,0 c 1.46,-1.455 2.075,-5.83 3.575,-9.6 0.61,-1.525 2.405,-8.38 2.73,-8.265 7.325,-1.41 4.72,10.095 -3.19,9.52
                                    -0.975,1.895 -1.705,3.845 -1.76,3.805 14.515,-4.01 14.125,-14.385 5.7985,-15.67 -0.44,-0.674 0.405,-2.08 0.175,-2.795 l -16.455,-0.45 z M -0.9995,29.895 c 1.1085,2.5585 5.11,4.03 7.325,4.49 l 14.705,0 14.7015,0 c 2.215,-0.4595 6.105,-1.81 7.2145,-4.37 l -20.62,0.235 z" >
                       
                           <!-- Animation of drawing the contours of a cup                       -->
                        <animate id="an_cup_body" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="svg1.click" dur="4s" values="234;0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />  
                               <!-- Cup fill animation                       -->
                        <animate id="an_fill_cup" attributeName="fill" begin="an_cup_body.end-1s" dur="1s" from="transparent" to="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2)" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
                        </path>         
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g class="flowerpot" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.4)" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="207" stroke-dashoffset="207" >
                <path fill="none" opacity="1"
                    d="M103,171 C 102,207 105,226 118,238 L183,238 C 195,228 200,205 198,170.5" transform="translate(750,113)"/>
                <line x1="852.5" y1="283.5" x2="948.3" y2="283.5" /> 
                <animate id="an_flower" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_smoke.end" dur="1s" values="207;0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />     
            </g>
            <g class="plant" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.4)" stroke-width="1" stroke-dasharray="265" stroke-dashoffset="265">
                <line x1="900" y1="150" x2="900" y2="283.5" />
                <path fill="none" opacity="1" transform="translate(750,20)"
                      d="M149,244 C 135,240 120,246 100,217 C 126,218 137,228 150,244 C 164,224 172,219 191,218 C 183,239 169,241 150,244" />
                <path fill="none" opacity="1" transform="translate(750,15)"
                d="M150,209 C 127,209 108,202 90,176 C 126,179 135,191 150,208 C 157,189 176,177 197,176 C 181,208 165,208 149,209" />

                <path fill="none" opacity="1" transform="translate(728,-10) scale(1.15)"
                      d="M150,168 C 133,166 122,159 114,148 C 130,149 141,153 150,167 C 155,151 166,148 178,145 C 170,163 159,167 150,168" /> 
                <animate id="an_plant" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="an_flower.end" dur="2s" values="265;0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />       
            </g>
        </svg>
      </div>
```

Comment: @Gloria Chen I did what I promised. Please see the animation version. Now you have the opportunity, if you like the answers, vote for

Answer (score 0):

to make SVG responsive you should set width=100% and set Viewbox attribute of Svg element
for example

```
<svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" >
....
</svg>
```

here is your fixed code

```html
 <div class="carousel-item active svg-container" style="height:352px;">
            <svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                <line x1="0" y1="352px" x2="100%" y2="352px" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.4)" stroke-width="1"/>
                <g class="kitchen" transform="translate(400,0)">
                    <g class="kitchen-cabinet" stroke-width="1.5">
                        <rect x="50" y="0" rx="3" ry="3" width="175" height="110" fill="none" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2)" filter="url(#f1)"/>
                        <line x1="137.5" y1="0" x2="137.5" y2="110" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.15)" />
                        <defs>
                            <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" width="110%" height="110%">
                            <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceGraphic" dx="2" dy="2" />
                            <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="1" />
                            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
                            </filter>
                        </defs>
                    </g>
                    <g class="kitchen-table" stroke-width="1">
                        <polygon points="-5.5,200 295.5,200 290,205 0,205" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.1)" fill="rgba(153, 102, 51, 0.5)"/>
                        <line x1="0" y1="265" x2="290" y2="265" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2)" />
                        <line x1="0" y1="205" x2="0" y2="100%" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.3)" />
                        <line x1="290" y1="205" x2="290" y2="100%" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.3)" />
                        <path id="kitchen-kettle" fill="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2)" d="M1136.74,509.923h-102.07c-3.036,0-6.035,0.782-8.664,2.257c-2.623,1.445-4.867,3.578-6.492,6.17L859.262,776.122
                        l-17.655-84.057c43.938-30.096,80.571-70.813,105.963-117.813c26.483-49.065,40.481-104.696,40.481-160.881
                        c0-65.256-18.516-128.539-53.546-183.009c-33.875-52.69-81.448-94.673-137.766-121.563c0.166-0.961,0.33-1.922,0.496-2.925
                        l0.466-2.79c1.075-6.449-0.691-13.101-4.972-18.726c-5.715-7.51-15.132-12.463-25.844-13.589
                        c-164.428-16.22-331.17-16.219-495.605,0.001c-10.705,1.125-20.123,6.077-25.838,13.588c-4.281,5.625-6.047,12.277-4.973,18.72
                        l0.433,2.644c0.17,1.031,0.329,2.022,0.486,3.012c-56.283,26.834-103.939,68.866-137.846,121.628
                        C68.515,284.833,50,348.116,50,413.371c0,56.184,13.998,111.815,40.481,160.882c25.508,47.21,62.334,88.063,106.586,118.256
                        l-74.045,352.551c-4.963,23.682,0.936,48.023,16.185,66.778c15.243,18.784,37.852,29.558,62.028,29.558h318.161h318.136
                        c24.167,0,46.784-10.772,62.055-29.558c15.231-18.766,21.121-43.107,16.16-66.778l-10.759-51.224
                        c63.816-0.731,108.188-47.532,135.596-143.067c13.684-47.695,21.321-99.839,28.06-145.845c4.112-28.069,7.995-54.58,12.613-74.716
                        c5.236-22.9,14.16-43.264,26.523-60.525c9.985-13.937,22.219-25.89,36.367-35.53c4.91-3.372,6.974-9.207,5.257-14.869
                        C1147.651,513.597,1142.68,509.923,1136.74,509.923z M188.251,1014.052c2.931-30.803,9.347-72.623,19.068-124.301
                        c16.52-87.817,37.172-174.998,37.38-175.867c0.788-3.323,4.12-5.38,7.447-4.589c3.324,0.789,5.379,4.124,4.589,7.447
                        c-0.201,0.846-20.287,85.638-36.64,172.028c-30.866,163.06-20.094,180.986-17.621,182.922
                        c24.801,11.26,234.416,13.742,313.081,13.742c3.417,0,6.186,2.769,6.186,6.186s-2.769,6.186-6.186,6.186
                        c-29.222,0-286.421-0.419-318.328-14.923C189.498,1079.371,183.061,1068.601,188.251,1014.052z M287.636,103.286
                        c2.78-0.396,280.087-39.395,465.474,0.072c3.342,0.712,5.474,3.997,4.763,7.339c-0.62,2.907-3.187,4.899-6.045,4.899
                        c-0.427,0-0.86-0.045-1.294-0.137c-183.222-39.007-458.383-0.324-461.141,0.072c-3.406,0.477-6.517-1.864-7.002-5.245
                        C281.907,106.905,284.254,103.77,287.636,103.286z M320.96,611.223c-2.992,0-5.487-2.124-6.062-4.946
                        c-0.081-0.401-0.124-0.815-0.124-1.24c0-0.423,0.043-0.836,0.124-1.235c0.572-2.825,3.068-4.951,6.062-4.951h364.451
                        c2.994,0,5.489,2.126,6.062,4.951c0.081,0.399,0.124,0.812,0.124,1.235c0,0.425-0.043,0.839-0.125,1.24
                        c-0.575,2.823-3.069,4.946-6.061,4.946H320.96z M633.6,1091.621c0,3.417-2.769,6.186-6.186,6.186h-49.281
                        c-3.417,0-6.186-2.769-6.186-6.186s2.769-6.186,6.186-6.186h49.281C630.83,1085.435,633.6,1088.204,633.6,1091.621z
                        M207.183,644.343c-33.961-26.496-62.124-60.789-81.499-99.319c-20.601-41.022-31.046-85.317-31.046-131.653
                        c0-54.592,15.022-107.793,43.441-153.854c27.179-44.094,65.552-80.124,111.045-104.339c0.001,0.008,0.003,0.016,0.004,0.024
                        l0.203,1.23c2.561,15.401,19.575,26.361,37.913,24.436c153.839-15.123,309.847-15.122,463.68-0.001
                        c1.411,0.149,2.813,0.221,4.201,0.221c16.683,0,31.353-10.435,33.695-24.646c0.071-0.406,0.131-0.803,0.196-1.206
                        c45.458,24.206,83.808,60.22,110.959,104.281c28.418,46.102,43.44,99.303,43.44,153.854c0,46.304-10.453,90.598-31.07,131.653
                        c-19.208,38.248-47.111,72.333-80.861,98.832l-4.962-23.628c-0.964-4.624-3.526-8.813-7.207-11.791
                        c-3.661-2.989-8.288-4.635-13.032-4.635h-53.733l-18.997-34.229c-1.775-3.191-4.396-5.876-7.58-7.765
                        c-3.19-1.875-6.82-2.867-10.499-2.867h-79.171l-14.413-24.214c-1.843-3.092-4.456-5.65-7.545-7.392
                        c-3.076-1.776-6.61-2.715-10.219-2.715h-52.967c-0.332-3.841-1.181-17.497,2.01-31.041c4.94-20.976,16.781-31.61,35.194-31.61
                        c9.092,0,17.169-1.908,24.005-5.671c5.699-3.138,10.571-7.621,14.48-13.328c4.341-6.365,4.707-14.256,0.979-21.111
                        c-3.731-6.832-10.574-10.913-18.308-10.913h-90.118h-90.144c-7.734,0-14.577,4.08-18.309,10.915
                        c-3.715,6.834-3.35,14.723,0.982,21.111c3.909,5.704,8.78,10.188,14.479,13.325c6.835,3.764,14.911,5.671,24.005,5.671
                        c18.445,0,30.285,10.635,35.194,31.61c3.187,13.53,2.339,27.198,2.009,31.041h-52.965c-3.609,0-7.143,0.939-10.208,2.709
                        c-3.1,1.748-5.714,4.306-7.556,7.397l-14.414,24.215h-77.612c-3.689,0-7.312,0.992-10.475,2.867
                        c-3.195,1.88-5.824,4.565-7.604,7.766l-18.997,34.227h-55.292c-4.743,0-9.371,1.646-13.027,4.631
                        c-3.685,2.981-6.248,7.17-7.213,11.793L207.183,644.343z" transform="scale(0.053) translate(350,2620)"/>
                        <g class="coffee-cup">
                            <g transform="translate(120,20)" style="fill:none;stroke:rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.3); stroke-width:2/5px;stroke-linecap:round;">
                                <path id="s1" d="M115,130 q6,6,1,9 t0,8" />
                                <path id="s2" d="M115,130 q6,6,1,9 t0,8" transform="translate(8,0)" />
                                <path id="s3" d="M115,130 q6,6,1,9 t0,8" transform="translate(16,0)" />
                            </g> 
                            <g transform="translate(223,165)" style="fill:rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.2);">
                            <path d="m 4.435,6.66 c 0.24,5.48 3.3455,19.43 6.9145,22.915 l 9.12,0 9.125,0 c 1.46,-1.455 2.075,-5.83 3.575,-9.6 0.61,-1.525 2.405,-8.38 2.73,-8.265 7.325,-1.41 4.72,10.095 -3.19,9.52
                                        -0.975,1.895 -1.705,3.845 -1.76,3.805 14.515,-4.01 14.125,-14.385 5.7985,-15.67 -0.44,-0.674 0.405,-2.08 0.175,-2.795 l -16.455,-0.45 z M -0.9995,29.895 c 1.1085,2.5585 5.11,4.03 7.325,4.49 l 14.705,0 14.7015,0 c 2.215,-0.4595 6.105,-1.81 7.2145,-4.37 l -20.62,0.235 z" />
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g class="flowerpot" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.4)" stroke-width="1" >
                    <path fill="none" opacity="1"
                        d="M103,171 C 102,207 105,226 118,238 L183,238 C 195,228 200,205 198,170.5" transform="translate(750,113)"/>
                    <line x1="852.5" y1="283.5" x2="948.3" y2="283.5" />
                </g>
                <g class="plant" stroke="rgba(76, 61, 104, 0.4)" stroke-width="1" >
                    <line x1="900" y1="150" x2="900" y2="283.5" />
                    <path fill="none" opacity="1" transform="translate(750,20)"
                          d="M149,244 C 135,240 120,246 100,217 C 126,218 137,228 150,244 C 164,224 172,219 191,218 C 183,239 169,241 150,244" />
                    <path fill="none" opacity="1" transform="translate(750,15)"
                          d="M150,209 C 127,209 108,202 90,176 C 126,179 135,191 150,208 C 157,189 176,177 197,176 C 181,208 165,208 149,209" />
                    <path fill="none" opacity="1" transform="translate(728,-10) scale(1.15)"
                          d="M150,168 C 133,166 122,159 114,148 C 130,149 141,153 150,167 C 155,151 166,148 178,145 C 170,163 159,167 150,168" />
                </g>
            </svg>
          </div>
```